# Deleting columns of a data frame with less than 1000 observations

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to remove all columns with less than 1000 observations. The approach below works fine, but is there any more elegant solution?

```
vec <- numeric()

for(i in 1:ncol(dat))
{
    if(length(dat[,i][!is.na(dat[,i])]) >= 1000) 
        vec <- c(vec, i)
}

dat <- dat[,vec]
```

Comment: Please add reproducible sample for good people here to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example What is structure `dat`? Can you paste output of `dput(dat)` here

Comment: This is a pretty broad question that applies to all `data.frame`s so I don't know what you'd expect to learn by seeing the object. `dput(head(dat))` would be a much better idea btw, since he's talking about 1000s of observations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
dat[,colSums(!is.na(dat))>=1000]
```

Here we first look which elements in `dat` are no `NA`, and compute columns sums of this new data frame. For those columns which contain at least 1000 observations we get `TRUE` and for others `FALSE`. So we can use it as an index variable which subsets original `dat` data frame.

Comment: while most logical answer in absence of data, we don't know yet what's  structure of `dat`. Ah well +1 anyway

Comment: You can change `>` for `>=` to get exactly the same the OP wants.

Comment: @geektrader He did say data frame and that his code works, so I though this should work always in those limits. But yeah, it would be nice to have somekind of note in Ask Question form about "dputting" your data..

Comment: @aguiar, why don't you accept the answer (to this one and your other questions)?

Comment: @Arun I can only accept it after 10 minutes. It's accepted now.

Comment: @aguiar, yes, forgot about that. Also consider accepting to your other questions.